# Series Majorized by a divergent series

Tags: real-analysis

I am working with a series $\frac{x_{n}}{n+x_{n}}$ where $\sum x_{n}$ is divergent.  clearly  $\sum \frac{x_{n}}{n+x_{n}} \leq \sum x_{n} $  where a divergent series majorizes an "unknown" series.  does this mean that  $\sum \frac{x_{n}}{n+x_{n}}$ is divergent ?

I know that for convergent series, we have convergence if a series is majorized by a convergent series, but what about divergent series?  thank you so much.

upon inspection, this confirms the series $\sum \frac{1}{n+1} \leq \sum \frac{1}{n}$  which holds.... both divergent.

Comment: Not necessarily.

Comment: The usual exercise involves $x_n/(1+nx_n)$, not $x_n/(n+x_n)$.

Comment: yes but was looking at a variation.

Comment: Could you give a hint on how to approach the usual exercise?  I'm actually stuck on that one.  thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$, then
$$\sum \frac{\frac{1}{n}}{n+\frac{1}{n}} = \sum \frac{1}{n^2+1}$$
converges.